# How to change a \NewDocumentCommand-based \cite command to accept biblatex-style arguments?

Tags: biblatex, biber, latex3, xparse

Over at [How to quote encyclopedia articles differently from books, magazines, etc. with Biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257354/how-to-quote-encyclopedia-articles-differently-from-books-magazines-etc-with?noredirect=1#comment617216_257354), I was greatly helped with a macro which solved the question as it was asked.

I'd now like to change this macro so that it works like a regular Biblatex cite command. Below is what I've attempted so far. Unfortunately it doesn't compile:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

% example bib file

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
  @mvreference{ml,
    title = {Müllers Lexikon},
  }

  @inreference{ml:thermoskanne,
    crossref = {ml},
    title = {Thermoskanne},
    volume = {2},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

% no quotes, italic font instead

\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\emph{#1}}

% shot at a solution based on cfr's original answer

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\parencitetitle}
  { > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { : } } m }
  { \myparencitetitle #1 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\myparencitetitle}
  { m m }
  {
    \boolfalse{citetracker}
    \boolfalse{pagetracker}
    \usebibmacro{prenote}
    \parentext{\mkbibemph{\MakeUppercase{#1}}:\citetitle{#1:#2}}
    \usebibmacro{postnote}
  }

% some sample text, etc.

\begin{document}

Some things need to be said, some things need to be written. One place to put them in is an encyclopedia.
This is what it should look like, just without the space: (cf. \citetitle[\emph{ML:}][]{ml:thermoskanne}, 234).
And this is what it looks like right now: \parencitetitle[cf.][234]{ml:thermoskanne}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

From what I understand so far, it is wrong (and impossible) to try and use Biblatex's `prenotes` and `postnotes` commands with this approach, and instead `SplitArgument` should be further exploited (how, though?)

Comment: Poor TeX code can hardly make you look like a disgrace to the human race!  Anyway, your code is far from disgraceful. (It doesn't work but that doesn't make it disgraceful.) Apart from the bit that doesn't work, it looks perfectly fine. (Believe me, that is not always the case!)

Comment: Of course your new command would somehow have to know that its crossref `ml` is to be displayed as "ML". We would have to have something like that in the `.bib` file. I would suggest changing to `@inreference` instead of `@incollection` (even if you didn't like the idea in your earlier question). As far as I can tell you will not need substantial modifications to your bib style, but it will make our life here much easier (you will have to change your `.bib` file of course, but probably not a lot).

Comment: Thank you :) Well, one question I had about your original code is why you put the first command after the second - it compiles, obviously, but I find it unintuitive that way (so it might just be a matter of taste). Also, why do people in the TeX world end lines with comment marks (`%`)? As for this thing here, am I right in assuming that only `SplitArgument` is a command of package `xparse`?

Comment: The main problem we have with this question here is that I'm not really sure whether one can make `\DeclareCiteCommand` accept additional arguments without a lot of fuss. What one could try to do (not what your title asks for exactly) is to replicate the behaviour of `biblatex`'s `\cite` commands as defined via `DeclareCiteCommand` in `\NewDocumentCommand \myparencitetitle` (`xparse` is quite powerful, and we will just need pre and postnotes).

Comment: According to the Biblatex documentation, @inreference and @mvreference are practically the same as @incollection and @mvcollection. If I understand correctly (which does not necessarily have to be the case, of course) the connection between the two is made solely by `crossref`. Since you say it will help, though, l've changed them here in the example. In real life, the change is a bit more complicated as it hinges on the resolution of https://github.com/ZotPlus/zotero-better-bibtex/issues/278#issuecomment-125677625.

Comment: @moewe: Such a solution (not useing `\DeclareCiteCommand`) would be just fine. I made the title like that because I thought that would be the only way to get `\cite`-like behaviour...

Comment: It would allow us to treat `@inreference`s (encyclopedia entries etc.) different from `@incollections` (which would not necessarily have to be a reference entry). And as you have said the treatment by standard styles is the same, so you would not face trouble from that side. So the only problem is your literature database programme.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26352/discussion-between-rainer-verteidiger-and-moewe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Biblatex solution may well be more elegant and efficient. I will leave that to moewe, I think ;). Here is a non-Biblatex solution which uses `xparse` to emulate the behaviour of the citation commands. I know that you expressed a preference for a Biblatex solution (option 2 in chat) rather than emulation (option 1) but perhaps this will be useful to somebody. Anyway, I was curious and, on the upside, this does not require making any changes to your `.bib` file because, on the downside, it knows zilch about that stuff.

Note that this adds a space after the colon. However, if you don't want this space, just uncomment the appropriate line and comment the one above it. I'm not sure which space you'd like to be without.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @mvreference{ml,
    title = {Müllers Lexikon},
  }
  @inreference{ml:thermoskanne,
    crossref = {ml},
    title = {Thermoskanne},
    volume = {2},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\emph{#1}}

% shot at a solution based on cfr's original answer
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\parencitetitle
{ o o > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { : } } m }
{%
  \IfNoValueTF {#2}%
  {% there is no second optional argument
    \IfValueTF {#1}%
    {% there's a first optional argument - pass as a postnote
      \myparencitetitle [] [#1] #3%
    }{% neither pre- or postnotes
      \myparencitetitle #3%
    }%
  }{% there's a second optional argument, so there must be a first as well
    \myparencitetitle [#1\addspace] [#2] #3%
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myparencitetitle}
{ O {} O {}  m m }
{\parentext{#1\mkbibemph{\MakeUppercase{#3}}\addcolon\addspace\citetitle[#2]{#3:#4}}}
%{\parentext{#1\mkbibemph{\MakeUppercase{#3}}\addcolon\citetitle[#2]{#3:#4}}}% use this line if you don't want a space after the colon (I'm not sure which space you want to be without)

\begin{document}

Some things need to be said, some things need to be written. One place to put them in is an encyclopedia.
This is what it should look like, just without the space: (cf. \citetitle[\emph{ML:}][]{ml:thermoskanne}, 234).
And this is what it looks like right now: \parencitetitle[cf.][234]{ml:thermoskanne}.

\parencitetitle[cf.][234]{ml:thermoskanne}

\parencitetitle[cf.][]{ml:thermoskanne}

\parencitetitle[234]{ml:thermoskanne}

\parencitetitle{ml:thermoskanne}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: emulation...]

Comment: Accepted this one for the correctly working space. Surprisingly, both answers here are shorter than the Biblatex-based answer over at the original question.

Comment: @RainerVerteidiger Look! I figured out how to get the space working with the blended solution ;). But I can only ping egreg there so I'm abusing the comment space here instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt to blend `xparse` with Biblatex.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @mvreference{ml,
    title = {Müllers Lexikon},
  }
  @inreference{ml:thermoskanne,
    crossref = {ml},
    title = {Thermoskanne},
    volume = {2},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\emph{#1}}

% shot at a solution based on cfr's original answer
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\myparencitetitle
{ > {\SplitArgument{ 1 }{ : } } m }%
{%
  \prefixparencitetitle#1}

\NewDocumentCommand\prefixparencitetitle
{ m m }%
{%
  \mkbibemph{\MakeUppercase{#1}\addcolon}\addspace}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencitetitle}
[\mkbibparens]%
{\boolfalse{citetracker}%
  \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}%
    {\printfield{prenote}%
      \newunit{\prenotedelim}}}%
{\ifciteindex%
  {\indexfield{indextitle}}%
  {}%
  \myparencitetitle{#3}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}%
{\multicitedelim}%
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}

Some things need to be said, some things need to be written. One place to put them in is an encyclopedia.
This is what it should look like, just without the space: (cf. \citetitle[\emph{ML:}][]{ml:thermoskanne}, 234).
And this is what it looks like right now: \parencitetitle[cf.][234]{ml:thermoskanne}.

\parencitetitle[cf.][234]{ml:thermoskanne}

\parencitetitle[cf.][]{ml:thermoskanne}

\parencitetitle[234]{ml:thermoskanne}

\parencitetitle{ml:thermoskanne}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: good blend]

## EDIT

Fixed spacing issue, I think!

Comment: `filecontents` should go *before* `\documentclass`; precisely, before loading `inputenc` or the ü in the title will be interpreted and not written out literally.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I didn't know that. I don't know where the environment is documented, although I think I have tried to find it. (I assume it is distinct from the documentation for the package.)

Comment: It's in the official LaTeX manual. The problem would be the same also with the package.

Comment: @egreg Lamport's book? I don't have it. Oh, well.